# Python GCD algorithms without using 'define'

Tags: python

I need to make two different types of codes to find GCD.
I'm not allowed to use def() because I didn't learn it yet.

This is my first code. I am not supposed to use the euclid method here.
I need to input two numbers together,
and set the smaller one to 'bound'.

```
num1, num2 = (input("input two integers to find GCD: ")).split()
num1=int(num1); num2=int(num2)


if num1 > num2:
    bound == num2

elif num1 < num2:
    bound == num1

i=2

while (i <= bound) :
    if (num1 % i == 0) and (num2 % i == 0):
        i == GCD
        i=i+1

print("The GCD for %d, %d is %d."%(num1,num2,GCD))
```

This is my second code. Here, I need to be using the euclid method.
I have tried my best, but I can't catch my errors.

```
num1, num2 = (input("input two integers to find GCD: ")).split()
num1=int(num1)
num2=int(num2)

temp=num1%num2

while (num1 != 0):
    num1=num2;
    num2=tmp;
    tmp=num1%num2

print("The GCD for %d, %d is %d."%(num1, tmp, num2))
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: for my first code, I don't understand how to set the smaller number to 'bound'. It returns errors.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include that question, as well as _what error exactly_ you are getting. Try to aim for a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

GCD for your first code:
Edit: You were using `==` instead of `=`

```
num1, num2 = (input("input two integers to find GCD: ")).split()
num1=int(num1)
num2=int(num2)


if num1 > num2:
    bound = num2

elif num1 < num2:
    bound = num1

i=2

for i in range(1, bound+1):
    if (num1 % i == 0) and (num2 % i == 0):
        gcd=i
        i=i+1

print("The GCD for %d, %d is %d."%(num1,num2,gcd))
```

GCD for your second code without using def using euclid method:

```
num1, num2 = (input("input two integers to find GCD: ")).split()
num1 = int(num1)
num2 = int(num2)
while num1 != num2:
    if num1 > num2:
        num1 = num1 - num2
    else:
        num2 = num2 - num1
print(num1)
```